# Заполнение матрицы бесконечной змейкой

Tags: java, python

Как сделать заполнение квадратной матрицы, как на рисунке
Прогаю на java или python[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуй просто представить себе алгоритм в голове пошагово и пиши код

1. Делаем один шаг в право
2. Делаем шаг вниз пока слева не будет пустая ячейка
3. Идём до упора влево
4. Делаем шаг вниз
5. Идем вправо пока верхняя ячейка не будет свободна
6. Идем вверх до упора
7. Начинаем с первого шага, делаем до тех пор пока можем ходить по условиям